# Truffle: Explain why does Truffle create 2 contract each time deploy to network

Tags: truffle

I am using Truffle for writing smart contract. When I want to deploy to test network (i.e: rinkeby network), I use following command:

```
truffle migrate --network rinkeby
```

As this is log:

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0xc032b44fb7d51ad386b6c1e7d9910798e36e1590b9fd557d50348af090ce06e3
  Migrations: 0x44b273afa97a8c0c1dac41b2f5972b22c0a92bb2
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x8fc27bea14c6c7e0bceac0c5232013211e8f7bd0cd05611935350b1fbf3c986b
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_game_presale.js
  Deploying GamePresale...
  ... 0x154df08d0d55d51fc2d2f78a8ac643f94b9cfde2eb5081e6b31d12367a7994ee
  GamePresale: 0x3cd9498845833058e48fde58e521f34420123793
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x789d608fd3302a931ef1ed744d50cfa63be24bde7d768c8508c0b978541e9b1f
```

Looks like that Truffle deploy to 2 contracts. So I go to `etherscan` for checking:

[image]

So based on this image, truffle has created 2 contracts. So my question is:

- Why truffle creates 2 contract.
- After every contract creation, truffle creates 1 more transaction. What is that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- The first created contract is the `Migrations` contract. This is a contract generated by `truffle init` and is needed by Truffle to do migrations and remember migration steps.
- After each migration step the `Migrations contract` is updated to store the step number in `last_completed_migration`. Each of your step contain only one contract creation but there could be more in each step.

  The second transaction stores 1 in `last_completed_migration`. The last transaction is executed after your second and last migration and store 2 in `last_completed_migration`.

Comment: So the first transaction is updates the migration state to "beginning" right ?

Comment: The first transaction creates Migrations. The second sets `last_completed_migration` to 1. The third creates GamePresale. The last updates `last_completed_migration` to 2.

Comment: thanks :D But why truffle needs to create this ? because I see, every time I run command deploy contract, truffle will creates new one from scratch. (i.e: create migration then create contract ...)

Comment: When the Migrations contract is already created, you can run the second migration only with the command `truffle migrate -f 2`. It will create `GamePresale` and update `last_completed_migration` in `Migrations`. It is more useful when you have more migrations steps: if a step fails it is not needed to redo all steps.